# Unable to run docker container in windriver operation system

Tags: docker, networking, wind-river-workbench

Our project is a microservice application. we run 5 to 6 docker containers using docker-compose and this is working fine in ubuntu, centos, and redhat. Am not able to run the same in windriver operation system. All the containers are sharing information using the docker network. when I start the service using docker-compose, am getting the following error.

ERROR: for my-service  Cannot start service my-service: failed to create endpoint my-service on network my-net: failed to add the host (veth78f811b) <=> sandbox (vethdd9d629) pair interfaces: operation not supported

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?